# Using Dependency Injection with Breezejs

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, breeze

I am building an EntityFramework/WebApi back end.
I want to decouple my WebApi from the Entity Framework, and utilize Dependency Injection so I can swap out the "data source" for the web API.
I have been looking at the Unit of Work and Repository patterns.

I also want to use [breezejs](http://www.getbreezenow.com/).

The breezejs TempHire samples has been alot of help, so I will use this as an example for my question -

https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js.samples/tree/master/net/TempHire

In this sample, on the data side we have the UnitOfWork class -

```
public class UnitOfWork
{
    private readonly EFContextProvider<TempHireDbContext> _contextProvider;

    public UnitOfWork()
    {
        _contextProvider = new EFContextProvider<TempHireDbContext>();

        StaffingResources = new Repository<StaffingResource>(_contextProvider.Context);
        Addresses = new Repository<Address>(_contextProvider.Context);
        // .. etc.
    }

    public IRepository<StaffingResource> StaffingResources { get; private set; }
    public IRepository<Address> Addresses { get; private set; }
    // .. etc.

    public SaveResult Commit(JObject changeSet)
    {
        return _contextProvider.SaveChanges(changeSet);
    }
}
```

Then on the WebApi side, it uses it like this -

```
[BreezeController]
[Authorize]
public class ResourceMgtController : ApiController
{
    private readonly UnitOfWork _unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork();

    [HttpPost]
    public SaveResult SaveChanges(JObject saveBundle)
    {
        return _unitOfWork.Commit(saveBundle);
    }
    // ... etc.
}
```

I would like to refactor to something like this, so that I could swap out the back end.

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork

public class ResourceMgtController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    public ResourceMgtController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork) {  
        this._unitOfWOrk = unitOfWork; // Dependency Injected...
    }    
    // ... etc.
}
```

What I can't wrap my head around, is how I can make it generic.  The breeze client needs a method like this -

```
[HttpPost]
public SaveResult SaveChanges(JObject saveBundle)
{
    return _unitOfWork.Commit(saveBundle);
}
```

And I can't put this in IUnitOfWork -

```
SaveResult SaveChanges(JObject saveBundle)
```

And really keep it decoupled from breeze, be able to swap out the back end for another backend.  Am I attempting the abstraction at the wrong point? I guess if I want breeze on the client I will need to couple it on the backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You clearly can define an interface with that method:

```
public interface IUnitOfWork {
    ...
    SaveResult SaveChanges(JObject saveBundle); // no problem
}
```

I suspect that you are objecting to the fact that both `SaveResult` and `JObject` are classes defined by libraries (`Breeze.ContextProvider` and `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq` respectively) you'd rather not reference somewhere.

These references wouldn't bother me any more than I mind referencing `System.Linq` to get `IQueryable`. In fact, a test double of `SaveResult` (a public class of `Breeze.ContextProvider`) is trivially easy to construct. Here is its definition (and the definition of `KeyMapping`, its only non-native dependent type):

```
public class SaveResult
{
  public List<object> Entities;
  public List<KeyMapping> KeyMappings;
  public List<object> Errors;
}

public class KeyMapping
{
  public string EntityTypeName;
  public object TempValue;
  public object RealValue;
}
```

But if *Breeze* and *Newtonsoft.Json* references are that noxious to you and you're willing to surrender some type safety, you can always create the interface like this:

```
  public interface IUnitOfWork {
     ...
     object SaveChanges(object saveBundle); // no safety, no problem
  }
```

Then in your concrete `UnitOfWork` you add a suitable overload:

```
public object IUnitOfWork.SaveChanges(object saveBundle)
{
    return SaveChanges((JObject) saveBundle);
}

public SaveResult SaveChanges(JObject saveBundle)
{
    return _contextProvider.SaveChanges(saveBundle);
}
```

... and Bob's your uncle.

Yes, I did try it (in DocCode); worked fine for me.

Comment: Thanks Ward. Your solution is what I ended up doing! You read my post exactly - I was objecting that I'm kind of adding breeze specific code in my generic interface - 
especially with having to add a method to return Metadata, which I didn't mention. If I wanted to swap it out for straight cache-less WebApi/EF solution, savechanges might look more like this -
public void SaveChanges() { _ctx.SaveChanges(); } and the Metadata would be irrelevant.  So I guess my UnitOfWork interface will need to be breeze compatible no matter the datastore.